Can Rails 8 support multiple Tailwind configs out of the box?
I have a Rails 8 application with two different areas (Admin/Site). All handled through namespacing.
I now want to introduce a totally different style to the Admin area and thus need to use a different Tailwind Ccnfig.
I note that the bin/dev command runs (in the Procfile.dev):
css: bin/rails tailwindcss:watch

Is it possible to parameterize or override this to build on two config files?
I'd like to avoid bringing in any npm packages for this.

A Rails discord server pointed me to this...
https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/discussions/355
It's not supported at present so will need to work around it for now.
